# Debian disable su to root user

Tags: linux, security, debian, su, pam

I am currently using Debian 7 (Wheezy) and I am trying to disable the `su` command only when the target user is root and not a privileged user.

For example, let's suppose the following users exist: `root`, `public`, `privileged`.

`root` would of course be able to `su`, without restrictions.

`public` should be able to `su` to `privileged` but not to `root`.

`privileged` should be able to `su` to root (or any user).

---

So far I have only been able to disable `su` to anyone but `root` and `privileged`, appending to `/etc/pam.d/su` the following line:

```
auth required pam_wheel.so 1005
```

Assuming 1005 is `privileged` uid.

However, this makes `public` unable to use `su`.

How could I make it?

Thank you!

Comment: Should `public` be able to `su` to _other_ users in the system? Should `public→privileged` require password? Should `privileged→root` require password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
auth sufficient pam_rootok.so
auth sufficient pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user = privileged
auth requisite  pam_succeed_if.so uid > 0
auth requisite  pam_unix.so
```

---

You could do this with `sudo` in an easier way:

```
privileged    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
public        ALL=(privileged) ALL
```